# NSMutableDIctionary setObject: ForKey crashing when Key is member of Object

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutabledictionary, sigabrt

I'm trying to use an NSMutableDictionary to pair my custom classes object with a UIButton as it's key.  The UIButton that is the key is also a member of the object that I want to store as the object in the NSMutableDictionary.

My Class definition looks like ths:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
@public
    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@end
```

And my implementation is just this:

```
@implementation ClassA
@synthesize button1, button2, label;
@end
```

The NSMutableDictionary is in another class.  I define it in the implementation like this:

```
@interface UIClass1 : UIViewController {
    NSMutableDictionary *Dictionary;
}

-(void)DoWork;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *Dictionary;
@end
```

And the part where I'm trying to set the Dictionary values is done here:

```
-(void)DoWork{
    Dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    ObjectA = [[ClassA alloc] init];

    ObjectA->button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ObjectA->button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    ObjectA->label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] autorelease]

    /* THIS IS A TEST AND IT WORKS FINE */
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test"];
    [Dictionary setObject:obj1 forKey:str];

    /*THIS IS WHAT I WOULD ACTUALLY LIKE TO DO */
    [Dictionary setObject:Object1 forKey:ObjectA->button1];
    [Dictionary setObject:ObjectA forKey:ObjectA->button2];
}
```

I've followed this code through my debugger and when I get to this line:

```
[Dictionary setObject:Object1 forKey:ObjectA->button1];
```

It just crashes SIGABRT.  None of my variables are nil, every object has been allocated.

Any ideas as to why I can't set the key to the button from ClassA but I can set it the the NSString I created as a test?

Comment: hey man, just a quick suggestion: make your variables camelCased!

Comment: Although you don't have to, almost all other Objective-C source code uses the lowerCamelCase convention for both variables and methods, and UpperCamelCase for class names. You are free to go against convention, but it's usually not advisable.

Comment: I actually do follow that convention, the code above is not my actual code, just a mock up of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you use as a key in an NSMutableDictionary must conform to the NSCopying protocol.

From Apple docs:

> The key for value. The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must
>   conform to the NSCopying protocol). The key must not be nil.

UIButton does not conform to NSCopying.

Comment: Ah ok that explains things.  Thanks.  Is there a list anywhere that outlines which objects are safe to use as a key with NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: I don't know of a list of iOS framework objects that support NSCopying but the docs for each object indicate which protocols they support.

Comment: You can use a NSValue object. Try [NSValue valueWithUnretainedObject:ObjectA.button1]

Comment: Im guessing what you meant was "valueWithNonretainedObject" which did work.  Thanks for the great help.

Comment: Yes i meant "valueWithNonretainedObject:"

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:ObjectA->button1]
```