# App rejection SIGABRT iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, exception, crash, sigabrt

I've recently got an app rejection because of an EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) exception.
The exception was thrown from within a try-catch block.

So I have 2 main questions:

1. Doesn't the try-catch clause in objective c catch all exceptions?
2. I have below the symbolicated crash log. on thread 7 (the one that crashes) i try to write in a NSMutableDictionary. That same dictionary is used (modified) on other threads also. Could this be the cause of this crash? (maybe 2 threads tried to modify the dictionary at once). If so, why isn't it there a second thread that tries to do the same thing in the crash log? Also: would @synchronize(a NSString for identifying that variable) {change my NSMutableDictionary / read from my NSMutableDictionary} solve my problem?

Thanks.

Symbolicated crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 1A82F42E-59AA-499A-8C1D-CE744808F566
CrashReporter Key:   4f2c8fa05c83e9d455c232dbd2fa63e852283d0e
Hardware Model:      xxx
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  7

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191179ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018408a570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184088764 __CFRunLoopRun + 932
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fc96cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   GraphicsServices                0x0000000189c65c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
5   UIKit                           0x00000001870fafd8 UIApplicationMain + 1152
6   brandnooz                       0x00000001000df500 main (main.m:16)
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000191097a9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191179aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107d998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191179cdc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   brandnooz                       0x000000010006fe9c __41-[RequestsViewController waitForRequests]_block_invoke (RequestsViewController.m:79)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191179ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018408a570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184088700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fc96cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x0000000184b652c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 292
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184bc2d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6   brandnooz                       0x0000000100115ed8 +[GAI threadMain:] + 68
7   Foundation                      0x0000000184c4c408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213e18 _pthread_body + 164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213d70 _pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192448 __psynch_rw_rdlock + 8
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190aaab84 lookUpImpOrForward + 164
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000190ab43f8 _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache + 56
3   brandnooz                       0x00000001000a14f8 -[AFHTTPRequestOperation hasAcceptableStatusCode] (AFHTTPRequestOperation.m:203)
4   brandnooz                       0x00000001000a0710 -[AFHTTPRequestOperation error] (AFHTTPRequestOperation.m:137)
5   brandnooz                       0x00000001000ebed8 -[AFJSONRequestOperation error] (AFJSONRequestOperation.m:99)
6   brandnooz                       0x00000001000ec128 __64-[AFJSONRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke (AFJSONRequestOperation.m:121)
7   brandnooz                       0x0000000100075a20 __47-[AFURLConnectionOperation setCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:321)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000184c34168 __103+[__NSOperationInternal _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:changeKind:oldValue:newValue:indexes:context:]_block_invoke96 + 24
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.high-priority
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   Foundation                      0x0000000184c338e0 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 100
2   brandnooz                       0x00000001000b71f0 -[ApiConnection get:] (ApiConnection.m:152)
3   brandnooz                       0x0000000100104b2c __38-[ApiRequests getTranslationsForCode:]_block_invoke (ApiRequests.m:185)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.high-priority
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019119258c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000191126804 abort + 108
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001911cc5c0 nanozone_error + 292
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001911cbd5c nano_free_definite_size + 128
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840ca268 __rehashd + 236
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fd1814 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 648
6   brandnooz                       0x0000000100103f84 __22-[ApiRequests getFaq:]_block_invoke (ApiRequests.m:120)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.high-priority
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   Foundation                      0x0000000184c338e0 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 100
2   brandnooz                       0x00000001000b71f0 -[ApiConnection get:] (ApiConnection.m:152)
3   brandnooz                       0x00000001001038e8 __24-[ApiRequests getTerms:]_block_invoke (ApiRequests.m:84)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.high-priority
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   Foundation                      0x0000000184c338e0 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 100
2   brandnooz                       0x00000001000b71f0 -[ApiConnection get:] (ApiConnection.m:152)
3   brandnooz                       0x00000001001060b4 __46-[ApiRequests getProductsWithKickbackForCache]_block_invoke (ApiRequests.m:307)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107c010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019107bfd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910832b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001910834f8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001912116b8 _pthread_wqthread + 352
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019120cdc8 _platform_memmove + 40
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fe205c dataWrite + 176
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fe1dc8 CFWriteStreamWrite + 440
3   brandnooz                       0x0000000100077e3c -[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:didReceiveData:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:797)
4   Foundation                      0x0000000184b82894 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 76
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184b82780 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184b82678 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
7   Foundation                      0x0000000184b82a7c _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData + 76
8   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183caf320 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic23_delegate_cacheTrifectaEPK20_CFCachedURLResponseU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 428
9   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183cab6e0 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 92
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fc908c CFArrayApplyFunction + 64
11  CFNetwork                       0x0000000183c20be8 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 132
12  CFNetwork                       0x0000000183c20a64 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 284
13  CFNetwork                       0x0000000183c208a0 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 56
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018408b040 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018408a39c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 252
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184088634 __CFRunLoopRun + 628
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fc96cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
18  Foundation                      0x0000000184b652c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 292
19  Foundation                      0x0000000184bc2d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
20  brandnooz                       0x000000010007533c +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:193)
21  Foundation                      0x0000000184c4c408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213e18 _pthread_body + 164
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213d70 _pthread_start + 136
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211550 thread_start + 0

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001911bf020 free + 72
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184088b38 __CFRunLoopRun + 1912
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183fc96cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
3   Foundation                      0x0000000184bbe424 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 344
4   Foundation                      0x0000000184c4c408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211550 thread_start + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191192e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 21 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019119276c __select + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213e18 _pthread_body + 164
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191213d70 _pthread_start + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191211550 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x00676f6c7379732f   x7: 0x0000000000000110
    x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000a  x11: 0x0000000000000007
    x12: 0x0000000000000037  x13: 0x00000001001814dc  x14: 0x0000000000000071  x15: 0x0000000004060401
    x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000001030301  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
    x20: 0x0000000103180000  x21: 0x0000000100258000  x22: 0x00000001911d3053  x23: 0x0000000178037e20
    x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001914e4000  x26: 0x00000001914e4000  x27: 0x0000000000000003
    x28: 0x0000000000000003  fp: 0x000000010317fc50   lr: 0x000000019121516c
    sp: 0x000000010317fc30   pc: 0x000000019119258c cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Code sample:

```
-(void) getFaq:(NSString*)ln
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [self.isDone setObject:dispatch_group_create() forKey:TAG_GET_FAQ];

    dispatch_group_async(self.isDone[TAG_GET_FAQ],dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        @try
        {
            ApiConnection* apiConnection = [[ApiConnection alloc] init];

            NSString* apiPath = [TAG_API_PATH_GET_FAQ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"LANGUAGE" withString:ln];
            id JSON=[apiConnection get:apiPath];

            [self.responses setObject:JSON forKey:TAG_GET_FAQ];                  //  <-- crash
            [self.processedResponses setObject:JSON forKey:TAG_GET_FAQ];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
            NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exception ApiRequests: %@", exception];
            [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createExceptionWithDescription:message withFatal:NO] build]];

            NSLog(@"Error in [ApiRequests getFaq] - possible null response");
            [self.responses setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:TAG_GET_FAQ];
            [self.processedResponses setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:TAG_GET_FAQ];
        }
        @finally
        {
            [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisibility:TAG_GET_FAQ];
        }
    });
}


Constants.h

extern NSString* const TAG_GET_FAQ;
extern NSString* const TAG_API_PATH_GET_FAQ;

Constants.m

NSString* const TAG_GET_FAQ = @"fooBar1";
NSString* const TAG_API_PATH_GET_FAQ = @"fooBar2";
```

Comment: Check if `JSON` is `nil`. For the `setObject:forKey:` API both obj and key should be non-nil. Also if possible add code for the `get:` method in `ApiConnection` code.

Comment: Please don't use `@try @catch` like you do in Java. This is not an appropriate programming pattern on Objective-C. In addition, your crash is not caused by an exception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that they key is not nil. Key's should comply to the NSCopying protocol.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061163/1734518)

and in the **Apple docs**

```
The key for value. Note that when using key-value coding, the key must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”).
```

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: the key can't be nil ... it's a constant that i've declared in a Constants.h soruce file and initialised in a Constants.m source file :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some memory corruption, which could have happened anywhere in your code. No exception is thrown, therefore no exception can get caught.

Answer (score 0):

On a strict reading of your code,

```
TAG_API_PATH_GET_FAQ = @"fooBar2";
```

means that

```
[TAG_API_PATH_GET_FAQ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"LANGUAGE" withString:ln];
```

will be `fooBar2`.

I am guessing this will make

```
            id JSON=[apiConnection get:apiPath];
```

return nil. I say this because your registers

```
Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x00676f6c7379732f   x7: 0x0000000000000110
x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000a  x11: 0x0000000000000007
```

are mostly zero (a tell tale of getting back a nil to underlying routines).

Did you forget to update the fooBar2 with a correct value?  If you have deliberately obscured the real value of this, can you replace your posting with something closer to the actual example, please.

Also, the use of try-catch does not match the Apple house style (which you might disagree with).  The try-catch is for programming errors not badly responding external systems.

If you have a hot data structure (concurrent adds/removes) it is worth investing in logging around all updates to your data and possibly have asserts.